# Need To Revert Multiple Controls Back To Previous Values

Tags: vb.net, controls, undo

I have the following situation where I have multiple controls on a form.  The user can select an Edit mode which allows them to modify the contents of the controls (textboxes, checkboxes, comboboxes, etc.) After editing has been made, the user can either select the Save or Cancel button.

Obviously clicking on save will save all changes to the database, however, if the user clicks on cancel, I want to 'somehow' revert all controls back to their previous state.

Currently, when the user clicks on cancel, the form turns off edit mode, but the controls remain with all the changes made until they reload the form.

Is there an easy way around this, or do I need to reload the entire form content from the database each time the user clicks on cancel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is reloading the data from the DB such a problem? Surely that only involves executing your form initialisation code, right?

Comment: Not really a problem no.  But the initial load from the database populates a lot of data on the form (un-editable data included) and I only have a need to reload a portion of it when the user clicks cancel.  If there is no simple way around this, I will either have to split my load sequence into two parts or just reload the entire contents each time.  I just thought I would put the question out there first before resorting to this solution.

Comment: I suppose you could mark the control as being modified when the user edits it and only reload the data for that control? Or maybe you could create a copy of the control, either crate an actual copy or have a class that stores the id and text values, manage these values in a list and then loop through the list and set the values back on the controls for which you stored the ids in the list? That's the simplest way I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: This is a good reason not bury your code in events.  If you had a `DisplayCustomer` procedure it can be called easily from form Load; but then for UnDo or in this case, Cancel, you just invoke it again to display the previous values.

Comment: Are your controls databinding to properties on an object?  How about using CSLA.NET and just calling a CancelEdit on the underlying object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to outline a possible solution here.

You could have a dictionary in your form in which you store the content of your controls whenever a user first modifies them, indexing them by the control name.

When the user starts modifying a control, you check if the control already exists in the dictionary. If it doesn't you add a new entry to the dictionary with the current value of teh control.

If the user cancels the editing process, you can loop through the dictionary, find each control in your form by its name (`Form.Controls(ControlName)` or something like that I think), set its value back to what it was and remove the entry from the dictionary.

It's not the most elegant solution as it will involve linking up all your controls to the `TextChanged` event or equivalent to capture their value when they are modified...

To avoid that, you could fill the dictionary right at the start when you load your form, after populating the values from the DB and then only set those controls' value back which have a different value when the user cancels.